# get cd/dvd drive or flash drive name by actionscript 3 in AIR application(in windows)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I am creating an AIR application using flex3 and actionscript3. there, i need to display dir content of cd drive/usb drive entered by user. how can i get cd/dvd drive name by actionscript3 ? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can a listing of a 'disk' location using the File's [getDirectoryListing()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#getDirectoryListing%28%29) this code:

```
var myDirectoryListing : Array = File.getDirectoryListing()
```

However, there is no way to tell what type of drive you're accessing; whether it be an internal hard drive, an external hard drive, a CD/DVD Drive, or a USB Stick.

One solution is to have users choose the drive they want to see listings for.  I'd probably use the [browseForDirectory()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForDirectory%28%29) method.